# Is there an easy way to explore how the output of a function vary when parameters are adjusted in R?

Tags: r

I am applying a method to a data set and am trying to determine its sensitivity to each parameter. There are 'generic' values used by the method, but I'm curious how the output would differ if each were bigger or smaller. It may be easier to describe using a simple example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

data <- data.frame(let = c("Alpha","Beta","Gamma","Delta"), num = c(1,2,3,4))

data$var = NA

ftn <- function(df, A, B, C){
  df %<>% mutate(var = num * (A*3 + B*(2/3) - C))
}

data <- ftn(data, A = 4, B = 2, C = 6)
```

The ftn function above takes A, B, C, which I've given as having the generic values of 4, 2 and 6. I am curious how the output (var) would change if each were multiplied separately by 0.5, 1 and 1.5.

In other words, I'd want to see what would happen if:

- **A = 2**, B = 2, C = 6
- **A = 4**, B = 2, C = 6
- **A = 6**, B = 2, C = 6
- A = 4, **B = 1**, C = 6
- A = 4, **B = 2**, C = 6
- A = 4, **B = 3**, C = 6
- A = 4, B = 2, **C = 3**
- A = 4, B = 2, **C = 6**
- A = 4, B = 2, **C = 9**

The long term goal is to produce a pointrange plot with the average 'var' being y and the changed variable along the x, so perhaps the eventual output would look like:

```
+-------------------+------+-----+------+
| Changed Parameter | x1.5 | x1  | x0.5 |
+-------------------+------+-----+------+
| A                 |   20 |  10 |   5  |
| B                 |   15 |  10 |   3  |
| C                 |   12 |  10 |   1  |
+-------------------+------+-----+------+

# NB: Numbers aren't right here, just for example #
```

So that it would be a case of plotting x1 vs Changed Parameter, with ymin = x0.5 and ymax = x1.5.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to achieve this without just manually changing numbers. I have tried to simply enter a vector (e.g. A = c(2,4,6)) but that didn't work. I appreciate it wouldn't take too long in this reproducible example to just change things manually and write them out separately, but in my actual code it would be a real faff to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you are doing. One way to do this would be to use some tricks from `crossing` from the `tidyr` package to make your design matrix. Then you can use `nest` and `map` to get your results. This would look like the following:

```
# Cross makes the model grid
crossing(A = c(2,4,6), B = c(1,2,3), C = c(3,6,9), num = c(1,2,3,4)) %>% 
  mutate(scenario_id = row_number()) %>%  # ID for grouping
  group_by(scenario_id) %>%  # Group for nesting
  nest() %>%  # Nesting
  mutate(result = map(data, ftn)) %>%  # Now apply your function for each scenario
  unnest() # Return the result
```

Which will give you something like this:

```
# A tibble: 108 x 10
   scenario_id     A     B     C   num    A1    B1    C1  num1     var
         <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1           1     2     1     3     1     2     1     3     1   3.67 
 2           2     2     1     3     2     2     1     3     2   7.33 
 3           3     2     1     3     3     2     1     3     3  11    
 4           4     2     1     3     4     2     1     3     4  14.7  
 5           5     2     1     6     1     2     1     6     1   0.667
```